# determine which button was clicked in HTML form - NOT submit type

Tags: html, prototypejs

I do NOT want the type="submit" because it changes the page -
I'm submitting thru ajax.. so I'm using type="button"

```
<input type="button" value="This is a submit button" name="submit1" onClick="submitMe( this.form )">
<input type="button" value="Another submit button" name="submit2" onClick="submitMe( this.form )">
<input type="button" value="Yet another submit button!" name="submit3" onClick="submitMe( this.form )">
```

However ALL the button names appear as passed form variables - I'd expect only the clicked button to be passed, like checkboxes or submit buttons...(if its NOT selected - don't pass it)

how can I determine WHICH button was selected - I need this because the action will be different based on button.

Using prototype 'AJAX.UPDATER' to handle the form.

The JS looks like this...

```
function submitMe( frm ) {
    var div = 'msgDiv';
    var url = 'mypage.aspx';
    var pars = Form.serialize( frm ); 
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater( div, url, { asynchronous:true, method:'post', parameters:pars    });
}
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `observe` or `on()` methods instead of the normal `onclick` attributes - for your html add a class

```
<input type="button" value="This is a submit button" class="submitbutton" name="submit1" >
<input type="button" value="Another submit button" class="submitbutton" name="submit2" ">
<input type="button" value="Yet another submit button!" class="submitbutton" name="submit3" >
```

if you attach an observer to your form by giving it an `id` of "myform" the "click" event will bubble up from the button to the parent form and you can find out what button the click originated from using the `findElement()` method on the event that is passed like so. In this instance I would use the `on()` method as you can specify a CSS selector to limit the scope of the event handling. Otherwise every click would fire the handler.

```
$('#myform').on('click','.submitbutton',function(event){
    var clickedbutton = event.findElement();

    //then you can fire your submitMe() function
    submitMe(this);
});
```

in the `on()` method `this` is the element that is being observed

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<input id="a" type="button" value="This is a submit button" name="submit1" onClick="submitMe(this.id)">
<input id="b" type="button" value="Another submit button" name="submit2" onClick="submitMe(this.id)">
<input id="c" type="button" value="Yet another submit button!" name="submit3" onClick="submitMe(this.id)">
```

and then in your JS

```
submitMe(id){
  switch(id)
  {
  case 'a':
    -----
    break;
  case 'b':
    -----
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: the prob there is I'm passing the form already...
submitMe( this.form ); and the js 

submitMe( frm ) {
var params = Form.serialize( frm);
...
}

Comment: mmm if you pass only "this" and in your function take "form" and "id"??

Comment: That works too, but i mean, submitMe(this)... and in your function: sumbmit(obj){ form = obj.form, id= obj.id ...}

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML code you can use id attribute instead of name And pass the id of the clicked button to the function ...

```
<input type="button" value="This is a submit button" id="submit1" onClick="submitMe( this.id)">
<input type="button" value="Another submit button" id="submit2" onClick="submitMe( this.id)">
<input type="button" value="Yet another submit button!" id="submit3" onClick="submitMe( this.id)">
```

Then in your JS you can get the formId by...

```
function submitMe(eleId) {
    var clickedButton = eleId // use it as you want
    var frm = $(eleId).up('form'); // this will give the parent form 
    var div = 'msgDiv';
    var url = 'mypage.aspx';
    var pars = Form.serialize( frm ); 
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater( div, url, { asynchronous:true, method:'post', parameters:pars    });
```

}